# Interactive cards hangout chat Api

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I'm using interactive card to send a message async to hangout chat API, and I used onClick.action but, when I do the action and click the button, I receive this error:

CARD_CLICKED_ERROR:
[image: CARD_CLICKED_ERROR]

Not that I handled card_click event type by adding actionResponse to a `NEW_MESSAGE` in reply message.

Comment: How is the object you are sending in the response to CARD_CLICKED event? Make sure it matches the [corresponding format](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#responding_to_clicks_with_a_new_or_updated_message)